# Automatic Differentiation in R

Tags: r, automation

I need to perform optimization using a custom function in R. For the sake of argument, my complicated function is

```
 ComplicatedFunction<-function(X){X*exp(-X/cummax(X))}
```

How would I, in a fast and automated fashion, extract the gradient and hessian.

A simple example is mean square error. MSE<-function(X){mean(X**2)}. The gradient is X and the hessian just just a bunch of 1s

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: The most specific I can get is asking if there is something that can find the gradient and Hessian of something like the listed ComplicatedFunction. This is basically a question if it can functionally find an answer. Ive provided a simple example MSE as a simple answer

Comment: These functions exist in Python under Auto Differencing. I have not found any such functions in R with full functionality. This is a very important question going forward because auto-differencing is ubiquitous in multiple fields.

Comment: Are you really sure you need this? jacobian and hessian from the numDeriv package tend to give very good results based on numeric differentiation and are very easy to use.